# Running a FreeBSD binary on Linux using qemu-user

Tags: linux, freebsd, qemu

I want to run a FreeBSD binary on Linux using qemu-user (qemu-i386).

This is the binary I'm trying to run: https://tug.org/texlive/xz/xz.i386-freebsd

This is the emulator I'm using: https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/releases/download/v3.1.0-2/qemu-i386-static

I've downloaded FreeBSD's ld-elf.so and libc.so.7 from http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/i386/11.0-RELEASE/base.txz and http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/i386/9.3-RELEASE/base.txz

However, I'm getting segfaults and weird system calls in `strace -f ./qemu-i386-static ./xz.i386-freebsd`.

Just as a sanity check, running `./qemu-i386-static ./xz.i386-linux` works, so *qemu-i386-static* can run Linux i386 binaries.

Is my use case (running FreeBSD binaries on Linux) supported by qemu-user? If it's supported, then how can I make it work?

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of [Running FreeBSD binaries on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/288989/running-freebsd-binaries-on-linux) , because here I'm trying to use qemu-user, and in the other question they try to run the binaries natively.

Comment: strace will actually monitor what qemu-i386-static itself does, not what the executable does. I am actually looking for a way to have qemu collaborate and do a strace on its own

Comment: @PaulStelian: I already know this: *strace will actually monitor what qemu-i386-static itself does, not what the executable does.* The reason why strace reports weird system calls can be that *qemu-i386-static* treats *xz.i386-freebsd* as if it was a Linux executable, and doesn't apply any system call mapping from FreeBSD to Linux. So either *qemu-i386-static* doesn't have the feature I need, or I'm not using it correctly. Hence my question on SO.

Comment: Ah, I doubt qemu-user has a feature to run a Linux executable on a non-Linux Unix system, or viceversa. I suppose you are running the BSD version of qemu-i386-static right?

Comment: @PaulStelian: The downloading link to the `qemu-i386-static` executable I'm using is in the question. It's unlikely to be a *BSD version*.

Comment: Anyway `qemu-i386-static` will only emulate the syscalls on the host OS. BSD executables have different system call numbers (and possibly even means to do system calls) from Linux. So unless you get something specific to running BSD executables you won't be able to. Even if it's source compatible, it isn't binary compatible. (Also, apologize for the confusion in my previous comment)

Comment: From my looking up, system call numbers may actually match at least for the Unix-portable system calls, however the actual convention differs (Linux passes the arguments in registers while BSD passes them on the stack). Of course `qemu-i386-static` will obey the Linux convention since it's a Linux executable and only helps with Linux executable on the target (i386) architecture.

Comment: And quote: `Note: Not only do FreeBSD and Linux use different calling conventions, they sometimes use different numbers for the same functions.`. So not even system call numbers will always match. Of course, there are Linux-specific system calls and probably there are BSD-specific ones too.

Comment: It's technically possible to convert between a large subset a Linux and FreeBSD system calls (doing some simple, but call-specific logic for each call). The Linux binary compatibility provided by FreeBSD does something similar. My original question is how to do it with `qemu-i386-static`.

Comment: Well the thing is, unless someone writes a variant of `qemu-i386-static` that _has_ the support to do the conversion you cannot have such a conversion. If only the qemu team considered it important, it wouldn't take much effort to implement. Just... it isn't happening, probably.

Comment: You may want to look at https://superuser.com/a/1355224/235100

Answer (score 1):

It looks like qemu-user (https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/releases/download/v3.1.0-2/qemu-i386-static) isn't able to run FreeBSD binaries on Linux.

Instead of reporting an error message, it attempts to run them as if they were Linux binaries, which will quickly cause a crash, because qemu-user is emulating the Linux system call ABI, and the binary is trying to make system calls using the FreeBSD system call ABI.

It would be an easy improvement to make qemu-user report an error at startup time if it is run with a FreeBSD binary.